# How do I force ActiveRecord to load a belongs_to-has_one relation through a JOIN instead of 2 queries?

Tags: activerecord, join, include, belongs-to, has-one

I have the following models:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

If I wanted the User to be loaded with the Person when it is loaded I would do this:

```
User.includes(:person)
```

The problem is that that use 2 queries, which is fine, in a belongs_to-has_many relationship, but in this occasion I think it would be better to use a JOIN and just one query.

If I do `User.join(:person)` it will join the `:person` but withtout the select statment and as attributes of `:user`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using:

```
User.includes(:person)
```

executes 2 queries... BUT, if you need to use a column of :person on the query, ActiveRecord automagically detects it and converts the 2 queries in a single query with joins

```
User.includes(:person).where('person.name=?', 'something')
```

I never cease to be amazed by Rails ^^

Comment: You could also use #eager_load, which forces the association to be loaded in a single JOIN query.